# PHP MIME type application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml

Tags: .htaccess, browser, configuration, wap, wml

I have added the following to my .htaccess file

```
# MIME Types for WAP
AddType text/vnd.wap.wml .wml
AddType image/vnd.wap.wbmp .wbmp
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlc .wmlc
AddType text/vnd.wap.wmlscript .wmls
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc .wmlsc
AddType application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml .xhtml
```

However the file is saved as index.php and uses the following header:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml");
```

The file currently tries to download can anyone advise how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XHTML MIME type in addition to the existing mappings:

```
AddType application/xhtml+xml .xhtml
```

In addition, [AddHandler](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/handler.html) can be used to handle that content-type.